# Argument of type '(data: MyContact[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: MyContact) => void'

Tags: angular

[Argument of type '(data: MyContact[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: MyContact) => void'.
Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are incompatible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5l7z.png)

Answer (score 0):

public getAllContacts(): Observable<MyContact[]>{
let dataUrl:string= `${this.baseUrl}/contact`;
return this.http.get<MyContact[]>(dataUrl).pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
}

Comment: Please put <MyContact[]> instead of <MyContact> in services

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.